# Honeynet setup and testing

Tags: virtualization, vmware-workstation, honeypot

I am setting up honeynet system with two honeypots and honeywall roo cdrom on vmware workstation 12. Now honeypots are not pinging to each other or honeywall is unable to ping to honeypots. In honeywall i am getting error "**send msg operation not permittted "**. I want to know how to test my setup by ping tests and how to access walleye web interface. Here is my setup [image]

Comment: You've probably got them firewalled away from each other. Might've messed up your iptables configuration.

Comment: As it names implies, host-only interface allow the VM to talk to his host only and not to the whole network. This is a networking problem, not a security problem and should be moved to serverfault/superuser IMHO.

Comment: As per host only networking definition it can communicate with the host and other VM's with host only configuration.